# How do I add a simple website url in my report on Latex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am student and new to Latex. I am using WinEdt as editor. I want to add simple visited websites url's to my references section how do I get desired output?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  In particular, it would be good to have some sort of MWE to show how you intend to insert that URL.

Comment: Do you use a bibliography package for your references or do you enter all your references manually? The easiest way would be to familirise yourself with a bibliography package (like `biblatex`) and learn how to use it to make references in your document. When you are typeing in by hand and time is running out, you can add `\usepackage{hyperref}` to your preamble and then type your references like `Autor, A. (2015) Some Title. Online: \url{http://link.to.the/document.pdf} -- accessed 2016.02.12.`

Comment: @Honey Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

If you simply want to have a hyperlink in your test, use `\url{http://www.example.com}`.  This will require the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package in your preamble.

If you want to insert a reference to an online source and add that to a bibliography, then you'll need to add the relevant entry in bibliography.  This is slightly more complicated and it will involve you adding something like:

```
@online{example,
    title = {Example.com},
    url   = {http://www.example.com},
}
```

to you BibTeX file and inserting `\cite{example}` at the relevant places in your `.tex` document.  This will require the use of [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) or other similar package.  A quick search will give you plenty of questions about that and how to use it.

Comment: On a side note, if you're using `biblatex`, the `@online` entry type has a convenient `urldate` field. It will print "Visited on [date]" with most of the styles.

Comment: I did as you said, but no reference is added to the output

Comment: Thak you sooo Much. its working for me \url{http://www.example.com}

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
\usepackage{url}
```

in preamble and it works fine for all \cite{example} and \url{http://www.google.com} and \footnote{http://www.google.com}. In this case, example is an entry in biblatex file, as told by JP-Ellis

```
@online{example,
title = {Example.com},
url   = {http://www.example.com},
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, maybe you could have emphasized the difference between `url` and `hyperref`: in one case, the url won't be "clickable", but the package is lighter and causes less troubles.

Comment: Note that `biblatex` loads `url` automatically, so there is no need to load `url` explicitly there. If one uses traditional `.bst` styles, the `url` field might not be available for all styles.

Comment: I am student and making a report. for which i visited several websites. Now I want to add these website url to my report reference section as hyperlink on them. I tried the packages told by you and other seniors here, and as well as made .bibTex file. But nothing is working for me.

Comment: The references should be kept in .bib file and should be called into your latex file by giving the path to .bib file. In your latex file, you can cite any references by using \cite{}